# SQL expressions in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, expression, where-clause

suppose i have a field with counts and when I get some updated counts I want to delete the fields where the count went down

```
$query = "DELETE FROM $table
WHERE id='$id' AND ($count-count)<0;";
```

how would i do something like this (I don't think this works)

Comment: Why don't you think that works?

Comment: I'd write it as `count < $count`, but it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: hmm well it doesn't delete them correctly for me but maybe the issue is elsewhere. also can i do something more complicated like $query = "DELETE FROM $table
WHERE id='$id' AND ($count-count)<0 AND ($count-count)/100>.5;";

Comment: You can make the `WHERE` expression as complicated as you like.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in how you're assigning `$id` and `$count`. If you show more code, maybe we can help you.

Comment: tell us what the values of ID and $Count are, what's in the table. You can do this with a select `SELECT id, count FROM $table
WHERE id='$id' AND ($count-count)<0;`. This way you know the logic for the selection in the where is sound.

Comment: Please provide your sample data & desired output. Also, please let us know, you are passing all as parameters in your query id,table,count. Is that what you want ?

Comment: what is the diffrence between $count and count ?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without more information, but this seems typical:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE count < $count";
```